# Button Click event getting fired after rowdatabound for grid view

Tags: gridview, paging, custompaging

When I click on a button which is outside of the GridView in my asp.net page, the GridView rowdatabound event is getting fired before OnClick event for the button. I am using the button for custom paging so I need to reverse the order of these events. Any thoughts ??

Thanks in Advance,
- Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly because you are calling `DataBind()` on the GridView in the `Page_Load` event. You should note that `Page_Load` will always be called before the event that raised the postback... the `Button_Click` in your case.

I suggest reading up on the [ASP.NET Page Life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) to learn more.

Comment: Also, smells like a case where a databind in Page_Load does check for Page.IsPostback

Comment: yup, that's what it was. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps your gridview `enableviewstate = false`